# Find $c$ for $f(x)$ given stationary point and range.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A function $f$ is defined for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and is such that $f′(x)=2x−6$. The range of the function is given by $f(x)\geq −4$.

$\text{ }(i)$ State the value of $x$ for which $f(x)$ has a stationary value.

$(ii)$ Find an expression for $f(x)$ in terms of $x.$

I found the stationary value to be $x = 3.$ I also integrated the function to get $x^2 - 6x + c$. Now, how do I find $c?$

I strongly suspect there is something to do with $x = 3$ and $f(x) \geq −4,$ but I don't see how I can assume that $y$ is $-4$ at $x = 3.$ How do I know that the range cuts $f(x)$ off right at the stationary point?

Comment: For a parabola, the stationary point is the extremum. Alternatively you may complete the square.

Comment: Minimum value of $f(x) $ will occur at $x=3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Min value of $f(x) = -4$ which occurs at $x = 3$.

So, $y = f(x) = x^2 - 6x + c = -4,$ gives you $c = 5$.

So $y = (x - 3)^2 - 4$

$y + 4 = (x - 3)^2$

The graph -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$c$ is an arbitrary integration constant.

At the critical point $ f(x)=x^2-6x+c = c-9 \;$ is a minimum, that still contains $c.$

If $f(x)=-4$ then $c=5$.

So for $ f(x) \ge -4,\;c \ge 5. $